# Calculating DB backup size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to know the size of a database full backup file before we actually do the backup? I did some analyses and figured sp_spaceused could give a close figure but thats not all, there seem(s) to be one/more factors other than the used space that go into determining the size?

Has anyone been down this path before? Any ideas?

Comment: I am looking for a more specific answer. I checked the AdventureWorksDB bak size and the MDF and LDF sizes. That did not add up correctly. i.e. the bak = 164,755 KB ; MDF = 180,992 KB and LDF = 2048 KB.

Comment: As an aside, according to http://serverfault.com/a/484672/82769, an MS SQL compressed backup will typically be ~30% smaller than uncompressed.

Answer (score 9):

sp_spaceused should be pretty close if you look at the reserved space.

[Estimating the Size of your Database Backups](http://jmkehayias.blogspot.com/2008/12/estimating-size-of-your-database.html)

Paul Randal blogged recently about how to know how large your TLOG backup might be:

[How much data will the next log backup include](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/New-script-how-much-data-will-the-next-log-backup-include.aspx)

A combination of the two values, seems to be really close to the actual backup size in some brief testing.

Comment: thank you, I have reached thus far. Is it possible to get any further?

Comment: In retesting this, the numbers are only a few KB off in size from the actual backup that is taken I don't know how much closer to accurate you are expecting to get?

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty much the size of the mdf and ldf files.

Comment: This isn't correct since data files have free space that is not backed up.  You can test this by creating a 4GB database and then doing a backup.  The backup will be nowhere near 4GB in size.