# Checking if the specified disks have enough space for database backup

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you check if the specified disks or mount points have enough space for database backup.

Comment: If you're not using compression, the backup will be a *similar* size to that of your database (it might be a little larger, or smaller, depending on the active transactions). If you're using compression, it'll be smaller, but how much smaller is very hard to calculate; as that totally depends on your database. The "easiest" way is to actually perform a backup.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862018/calculating-db-backup-size) for estimating non-compressed backup size. `xp_fixeddrives` will report available free space.